# IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, maven

after I've added

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("org.sample")
public class SampleServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleServiceApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

my codebase multimodule structure is:

```
project
├── api
├── service
└── util
```

where api and utils are just java libraries and service is a springboot microservice

but when I build with `mvn clean install` I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   ServiceApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@14b789f6 testClass = org.sample.microservices.core.service.ServiceApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [org.sample.microservices.core.service.ServiceApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@738dc9b, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2892d68, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@78e4deb0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@470734c3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@75437611, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@a2815468], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
```

my Integration Test Class is:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ServiceApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

honesty I don't know how to deal when I have those kind of problems

Answer (score 1):

to solve this problem you have to edit your Integration Test Class with
`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)`